# Why is this not a Kan extension?

Tags: category-theory

Suppose we have functors $F:C\to E$ and $K:C\to D$ with some $H:D\to E$ such that $F=HK$. There is an obvious transformation $1:F\to HK=F$.

Question: Is this ($H,1_F$) a left Kan extension of $F$ along $K$?

I want the answer to be yes, but was told it was no.

We see that for any $G$ with a transformation $\alpha:F\to GK$ there is a unique transformation $HK\to GK$ factorising $\alpha$. This is true since $HK=F$, so that we can choose $\alpha$ as the unique one, and thus it is a left Kan extension.

Where does this argument fail?

---

edit: (thanks to Eric's answer)

A Kan extension should have a unique transformation $\beta:H\to G$ that induces the $HK\to GK$ above, and this $\beta$ doesn't always exist.

---

I worked out what I believe to be a counter-example.

For $F=HK$ it is not necessarily true that $H,1_F$ is a left Kan extension. Toy example: Suppose $C$ is a category with a single nontrivial arrow, and $D=E$ is a category with two nonparallel nontrivial arrows $f$ and $g$.

Let $K=F:C\to D$ map the single arrow of $C$ to $f$. Let $H:D\to D$ map both arrows of $D$ to $f$, and let $G=1_{D}$. Clearly $F=HF$ as well as $F=GF$. But there are no natural transformations (since $f,g$ have disjoint sets of sources and targets) from $H$ to $G$ so it can't be a Kan extension.

Comment: The unique transformation is to be of the form $H \to G$ and then it completes the triangle after precomposing with $K$.   How will you define the transformation from $H$ to $G$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is indeed a unique natural transformation $\alpha:HK\to GK$ as you claim.  However, what you need in order to have a Kan extension is not a unique natural transformation $HK\to GK$, but a unique natural transformation $\beta:H\to G$ such that the induced natural transformation $HK\to GK$ makes the diagram commute.  There is no obvious reason your $\alpha$ should come from a $\beta:H\to G$, or that the $\beta$ it comes from should be unique.

Comment: Thanks! Using the right definitions usually helps... :p